# Help me find a good font substitute for this handmade print

Tags: typography, font-recommendation, serif

[image: Old bookplate]

The image is an old bookplate I have, I wanted to find some fonts similar to the two types of characters here (which I'm 100% sure are hand drawn) but until now my research (used identifont, whatfontis and fontspring) has been unfruitful.

Comment: If you have access to Adobe Typekit try Eloquent JF.

Comment: I'd take this opportunity to create a font that matches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of at least somehow resembling candidates:

[image]

[image]

Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape etc...programs allow you to use fonts as unfilled.